# Multiple JPanels in one JFrame not showing top panel

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, jpanel

So I'm writing a program in which I wish to have a single JFrame containing a JPanel header in a separate colour and directly underneath have a grid of buttons in a separate JPanel.  So far my program works perfectly except for the fact that the header String isn't showing up in the NORTH panel.  Instead I'm getting a box containing the set background colour with a small grey box in the centre.  I'm wondering if I didn't set the size of the panel correctly?

I have heard this can be accomplished using JLabel, but when I tried to do this, it would not show the background colour that I had set.

So, could anyone please show me how to achieve the following either with the JPanel (preferably because I would like to know how it works and what I'm missing) or with JLabel: filling that little grey box in the middle of the header with a String.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize a panel for the header, and mainGrid which will contain buttons
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainGrid = new JPanel();

        // Initialize the header
        DisplayPanel message = new DisplayPanel();
        header.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        header.add(message);

        // Initialize the mainGrid panel
        mainGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,2,2));
        mainGrid.add(new JButton("1"));
        mainGrid.add(new JButton("2"));
        mainGrid.add(new JButton("3"));
        mainGrid.add(new JButton("4"));

        // Add the two subpanels to the main panel
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH); // The issue is this panel isn't displaying the String created in DisplayPanel
        panel.add(mainGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add main panel to JFrame
        JFrame display = new JFrame("Test");
        display.setContentPane(panel);
        display.setSize(200,100);
        display.setLocation(500,200);
        display.setVisible(true);
        display.setResizable(false);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawString("header" , 20, 20); // The string I want to be displayed
        }
    }
}
```

I would very much appreciate anyone's help or input as I have only been studying Java for a few months and this is my first post.  Thank you in advance.

Also, any general tips on writing that you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering if your problem is that you're nesting your message JPanel inside of the header JPanel, and the container header JPanel uses the JPanel default FlowLayout. Thus the component it holds won't expand on its own and will remain trivially small.

- Consider either giving the header JPanel a BorderLayout so that message expands inside of it, or
- use a JLabel to show your text, not a JPanel's paintComponent method. The JLabel should size itself to be big enough to show its text. If you do this and want it to show a background color, all you have to do is call `setOpaque(true)` on your JLabel, and you're set.

---

Actually, if you nest the JLabel, then there's no need to make it opaque. Just do this:

```
  JPanel header = new JPanel();
  JPanel mainGrid = new JPanel();
  JLabel message = new JLabel("Header", SwingConstants.CENTER);
  header.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
  header.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  header.add(message);
```

Comment: Thanks, the BorderLayout didn't work but the setOpaque() was what I needed.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: @SmithNineSix: you're welcome, and thanks for asking a question with a short compilable and runnable example program. That makes answering much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a GUI builder WYSIWYG IDE, like [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org), where you can easily drag and drop components to where they need to be. If you're doing any sort of complex GUI layout, it can be madness (and in my opinion, nonsensical) trying to write and maintain the code.

The layout your trying to implement would be trivial in NetBeans.

Comment: This is a great tool if you have a deep understanding of the foundations of Swing and especially the use of layout managers, but I don't recommend it if you're just learning Swing. Else while it is easy to create simple GUI's, the moment that you want to do something that's slightly off kilter, you're stuck. Trust me, we see questions from these folks all the time for this very reason.

Comment: While Form Editors have their place, it makes people very lazy and reliant on a given IDE.  If you work in an environment where people can use different IDEs, than a form editor becomes unavailable, as there is no uniform format for form editors. Sure you could suggest using a 3rd party tool, but that just raises the same arguments people have over IDEs.  Better to learn to hand the layouts to start with, it will simply make life easier in the long run - IMHO

Comment: I would offer a counter argument that you never truly learn the aspects of good HMI layout design without an editor. In my professional work, the dozen or so people I've encountered who prefer to hand program their GUI code have never learned good layout principles because it can too complicated to learn quickly. E.g., ensuring all fields are aligned properly vertically/horizontally, resizing appropriate components when windows are resized, setting up mnemonics and contextual menus when appropriate, etc.